# Keep event helper from disappearing

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar 2.3.2 to implement a create event functionality like in google calendar.

1. you drag on the day/week calendar
2. placeholder 'helper' event is created
3. popup where you input title and other info is shown
4. hit submit and event is created

My popup window shows up but the a click immediately after the mouse drag end (for creating the placeholder event) removes the placeholder event.

I need it to ignore mouse clicks in the popup window - like in google.
But I can't find out where it's listening for the click event to remove the placeholder event.

```
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    var endtime = end.format('h:mma');
    var starttime = start.format('ddd, MMMM d, h:mma');
    var when = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
    $popup.css({'top':jsEvent.pageY, 'left':jsEvent.pageX}).show();
    $('#cb-starttime').val(start);
    $('#cb-endtime').val(end);
    $('#cb-when').text(when);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moonjo/bc00cbks/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read through the [selection](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/) part of the docs, it will come in handy.

For what you want to do, it's as simple as turning [`unselectAuto`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/unselectAuto/) off. Then you can call it manually with [`.fullCalendar('unselect')`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/unselect_method/).

That said, the select helper is meant to be temporary. You should replace it with a proper event as soon as it is no longer temporary.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up rendering my own temp helper to take that place. Now I can clean it up..